# How to create and populate a `SparqlQuery` object without a parser?

Tags: sparql, dotnetrdf

I am trying to model a SPARQL query with the [`SparqlQuery` class](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlQuery.html).

It looks like I can use the [`RootGraphPattern` property](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlQuery.RootGraphPattern.html) property to specify the triple patterns to adhere to in the results to my query.

Unfortunately, I have so far failed to create an instance of the `SparqlQuery` class, as [its constructors are not publicly accessible](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlQuery~Constructors.html) and the class is sealed. Likewise, the [query type](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlQuery.QueryType.html) can only be retrieved, but not set. Is there any factory method with an obscure name that creates instances of that class?

Forum postings, just as the [documentation on the topic](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=Querying%20with%20SPARQL) exclusively generate their `SparqlQuery` instances based on query strings with the [`SparqlQueryParser`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlQueryParser.html) class. However, I *don't have* a query string yet, and I'm trying to avoid concatenating strings to build my query when there's an object-oriented API available that lets me construct my query in an OO way rather than starting out with a string.

Hence, my question is: **How can I instantiate the `SparqlQuery` class *without using an initial query string and a SPARQL parser*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can't, most of `SparqlQuery` is intentionally sealed because a lot of the properties and related classes like `GraphPattern` represent the AST and when we originally designed the class we didn't want people to intentionally/accidentally modify the AST in ways that created broken queries.

There is a [fluent-query](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/src/tip/?at=fluent-query) branch in the works which will eventually provide a Fluent API for building queries but the developer behind that is currently on a month long vacation and I haven't seen any activity on it for a while.  You can take a look at the [Fluent Query wiki](https://bitbucket.org/romanticweb/dotnetrdf/wiki/Home) for some examples of what this API is going to look like.

If this is an important feature to you we can push this up the priorities but as an open source project we are heavily constrained by the limited resources of our small developer team.

We could likely integrate what we have so far into our 1.0.0 release but our recent release focus has been on bug fixes and stability to make the 1.0.0 a stable production ready release, introducing a new and relatively untested feature goes somewhat against this.  Also the API does not yet cover all of SPARQL so would be incomplete and potentially unstable.

Comment: This looks very promising, but I would prefer a stable API over a quick-and-dirty release, so take your time :-) I can build my queries as strings for now; I can switch to using an object-oriented API that introduces some compile-time checking into my query contruction once it is ready.

Comment: Ok no problem, it is slated for 1.1.0 right now which is tentatively scheduled for end July.  As with any open source project schedules are subject to change/slippage due to varying availability of developers